# Can the gamma distribution act as conjugate in this MVN case?

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, gamma-distribution, conjugate-prior

I have a sort of an expression for a multivariate normal-gamma distribution as follows:

$$
P(\lambda|w) = P(w|\lambda) P(\lambda)
$$

$P(w|\lambda)$ is a multivariate normal with 0 mean and parameterised with the precision matrix given by $(\lambda\Lambda)$. $\lambda$ is a scalar.

$P(\lambda)$ is a gamma distribution with scale $s$ and rate $t$. I was under the impression that $\lambda$ would be gamma distributed. So, I have the following:

$$
P(\lambda|w) \propto \lambda^{s-1} \exp(-t\lambda) \:|\lambda\Lambda|^{1/2} \exp(-\frac{w'(\lambda\Lambda)w}{2})
$$

Now, the problem is it does not seem possible to formulate this in the familiar Gamma form when one of the terms is a multivariate rather than a univariate Gaussian?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$P(\lambda|w) \propto \lambda^{s-1} \exp(-t\lambda) \:|\lambda\Lambda|^{1/2} \exp(-\frac{w'(\lambda\Lambda)w}{2})$$

$$ \propto \lambda^{s-1}\lambda^{k/2} \:|\Lambda|^{1/2}   \exp\left(-t\lambda-\frac{w'(\lambda\Lambda)w}{2}\right)$$

where $k$ is the dimension of $w$,

$$ \propto \:|\Lambda|^{1/2} \lambda^{s+{k/2}-1}  \exp\left(-\lambda\left[t+\frac{w'\Lambda w}{2}\right]\right)$$

$$ \propto \:|\Lambda|^{1/2}\: \cdot\: \lambda^{(s+\frac{k}{2})-1}  \exp\left(-\lambda\left[t+\frac{w'\Lambda w}{2}\right]\right)$$

Which - up to constants - is clearly in the form of a $\Gamma\left(s+\frac{k}{2},t+\frac{w'\Lambda w}{2}\right)$ (if we're working in shape-rate form).

Comment: Oh wow...I did not know one could remove the scaling factor from the matrix determinant like that i.e. $|\lambda\Lambda|^{1/2} = \lambda^{1/2}|\Lambda|^{1/2}$! Not obvious at all to me! Thanks!

Comment: Yikes... actually, there's a mistake there! I will fix it

Comment: Hopefully fixed now. The correct rule is rule (5) [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant)

Comment: Thank you! May I ask, if it is at all somehow related to the rank of the matrix $\Lambda$?

Comment: The length of $w$ will be the (row and column) dimension of $\Lambda$ (which is presumably of full rank), so yes. I cast it in terms of $w$ only because it's a bit shorter to say "the dimension of w"

Comment: You are a star!

Comment: Luca, I just found another error; my star is looking a little rusty. I need a second cup of coffee this morning (well, it's morning in my part of the world). The form of the result was niggling at me (the signs didn't make sense) so I went back through it again and soon found the (basic) mistake. Now they all make sense.

Comment: Thanks Glen. It is 11 here, so I had left looking at it in more detail till tomorrow morning!

Comment: The sign on the $k/2$ term somehow acquired a minus sign (which then got carried through) when I fixed the taking-a-scalar-out-of-a-determinant. You can always see what was changed by clicking on the link (near the signature) on my post that shows how recently it was edited.

Comment: I did do that and edited my post but I see you beat me to it!

Comment: I mean that you can see how my answer was edited by clicking on the link to the left of my signature below my answer. It presently says "[edited 41 minutes ago](http://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/89942/revisions)"

Comment: I did :-) I had made the post and then realised it keeps track of all edits and then I came and changed my post but by that time you had already posted your reply. Anyway, this horse is dead! Thanks again for all your help. This matrix determinant trick was what I was missing. Tomorrow will be another struggle...

Comment: There is still one small mistake, i think. The third equation line should have: $\lambda^{s+\frac{k}{2}-1}$ rather than $\lambda^{s+\frac{k}{2}}$. So the final expression for the shape parameter becomes $s+\frac{k}{2}$.

Comment: Luca - I think you're right.